# Libgdx Back button exit the app

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I press back button on android, it exits the game although I ask it to go to other screen instead. It goes to the other screen for one or two seconds then it exits.:

```
if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)))
    game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game,4));
if(controller.isresumePressed()) 
{
    controller.table2visible(false);
    controller.table1visible(true);
    pausestate = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to tell LibGDX to catch the back key from Android. This only needs to be done once so you can do this in the onCreate() method of your main class.

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

Comment: thanks it is working very well, but is it the same way to catch the menu button ? I tried Gdx.input.setCatchMenuKey(true); then I added 
if((Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK))||(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.MENU))) 
but only back button work , when I press menu button and come back to game it starts from the previous position

Comment: Android moved away from using the menu button a while back, so any newer devices will not have a menu button at all. To access the menu I created my own menu button inside the program and use that to launch the menu. It's been a while since I used the Android menu button, but I believe they worked exactly the same way. So if you have a device with the menu button, then Gdx.input.setCatchMenuKey(true); should have worked. Can you explain more about what is not working with the menu button? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: no I didn't menu button in the old android devices, I mean the button at the middle of the android device next to back button, which go out from the program when u press on

Comment: That's the home button. There is no way to prevent it from working. Your game's pause method will be called when the game is hidden.